# Change Listen Address Web Logic

Tags: server, ip-address, weblogic12c, listen

I have a server running on weblogic 12c. But it is running on localhost:7001/myapp/.. 
I can run it by http://localhost:7001/myapp/... or http://127.0.01/myapp/... But only on the computer that weblogic is installed. 
I need to access from other computers. 
I have changed the Listen Address from localhost to my public IP, but when i did it, my server did not run anymore, it shows an error "Could not find lock file. Maybe the server is already running" something like that.
 I have already tried to delete the .lok file, but that did not work either. Tried to change the config.xml file, but that did not work either. 
Have this happenned to someone? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and below the answer, for stand alone Weblogic and even for embedded one, You want to change Listen Address, Just do the following steps:

1. If you have not already done so, in the Change Center of the Administration Console, click Lock & Edit (see Use the Change Center).
2. In the left pane of the Console, expand Environment and select Servers.
3. On the Servers page, click the name of the server.
4. Select Configuration > General.
5. On the Severs: Configuration: General page, enter a value in Listen Address.
6. Click Save.
7. To activate these changes, in the Change Center of the Administration Console, click Activate Changes.
8. Not all changes take effect immediately—some require a restart (see Use the Change Center).
9. For (integrated weblogic only) on JDeveloper, open Application servers from windows menu, select Integrated weblogic, right-click on it, select Properties, select Configuration tab, Change hostname with the same IP address you put in Console

if your Weblogic server isn't production server, just ignore steps (1 & 7)

reference : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50629_01/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/channels/ConfigureListenAddresses.html

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check what is running on 7001 port:

On windows use: netstat -ano|find /i "7001" it will give you something like :

TCP    0.0.0.0:7001    0.0.0.0       TIME_WAIT       1028

then you can kill that process using

taskkill /F /PID 1028 (java process started on 7001)

Now try to delete *.lok file from Domain/servers/AdminServer Path

and start admin server .

If you have nothing specified in listen address field it will listen on all the available network interfaces which can be check by ipconfig  command on window

On linux use netstat -tulp|grep 7001 to find process

Comment: @Man-l-n-MiddLeWare the command netstat -ano|find /i "7001" didn't give me back anything, so does that means that I have nothing runnign on the port 7001?

Comment: are you using windows or linux ? If that is windows and you are not getting any output of netstat -ano|find /i "7001" means no process is running on that port.  Then try to search for java process using  tasklist |find /i "java"  that will give you pid of that process.Then by using pid you can search port using nestat -ano|find /i "pid"

Comment: First check admin server logs for port listening it will show something like this:

<Jun 4, 2015 7:31:17 PM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" i
s now listening on 192.168.1.10:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>

<Jun 4, 2015 7:31:17 PM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]
" is now listening on 2001:0:kgbc:fd12:120m:2748:3f83:mjk7:7001 for protocols ii
op, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
<Jun 4, 2015 7:31:17 PM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[6]
" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> .

Answer (score 0):

Did you see check if there is another application running on your public ip and the same port ?

Comment: I'll try to do that. Do you know how to check all the applications running on the ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not at all clear. You say your server is running on a server and you can access it using the url http://localhost:7001/myapp/...

So that bit is clear.

Then you try to access your application from another machine. This where it gets confusing.

You say - "I have changed the Listen Address from localhost to my public IP, but when i did it, my server did not run anymore, it shows an error "Could not find lock file. Maybe the server is already running" something like that."

Why would your server stop running if all you did was try to access from a different machine ?

" The error could not find lock file " is usually seen when you try to start a server on a machine where there might be another server already running. But since your aim is only to access your already running server from a different machine you would do that using a browser, why start another instance ?

Could you throw some more light on what exactly you are doing and the result.

Few tips -

Check the listen address of your weblogic server from admin console.
Check if the server you are running weblogic has more than 1 ip. Run ifconfig or ipconfig to get the IP's